# Laplace transform of a convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the Laplace transform of the convolution of $e^{-t}*e^t\cos(t)$.

How do I write the integral of these two functions, what are the limits of integration?

So I guess my only question is how to write the convolution of these two functions.

Thanks so much, I apologize for the simplicity of my question.

Comment: The Laplace transform of a convolution is the product of the two transforms. Check the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)

Answer (score 0):

As @Dylan proposed you simply need to multiply the Laplace transforms of each individual function.

$$\mathcal{L}\{\exp(t)*\exp(t)\cos t \}=\mathcal{L}\{\exp(t)\}\mathcal{L}\{\exp(t)\cos t \}=\dfrac{1}{s-1}\dfrac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}$$

In control theory, the cancellation of the unstable pole-zero-pair should not be carried out.